# iOS restriction to play TS

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

Does iOS have any special restriction to play TS that Android or windows does not have?
I have written a java code to form TS from raw rtsp data(H.264). That TS files are played in android and windows but not in iOS.

If you guys want to check the TS files, I have uploaded some [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B11-QeDGHA7yMUYzSFVQWmZ3cHM).
Someone please help me.

Comment: which lib ur using ?

Comment: for what? ts formation or to play ts?

Comment: ok,, to play in iOS, here is the code:
playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
self.avPlayerViewcontroller = playerViewController;
[playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[playerViewController.player play];

Comment: Is this the problem of player or the file? I have tested with other standard TS files from internet, they are playing fine with the player.